# R - Replace values in a specific even column based on values from a odd specific column - Application to the whole dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

My data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(1,5,6,8,7), qA = c(1,2,2,3,1), B = c(2,5,6,8,4), qB = c(2,2,1,3,1))
```

For the case A and qA (= quality A): I want the values assigned to the quality value 1 and 3 are replaced by NA

And the same for the case B and qB

The final data has to be like this:

```
desired_data <- data.frame(A = c("NA",5,6,"NA","NA"), qA = c(1,2,2,3,1), B = c(2,5,"NA","NA","NA"), qB = c(2,2,1,3,1))
```

My question is how to perform that?

I have a big dataframe with about 90 columns, so I need code which doesn't require the column names to work properly.

To help, I have this part of code which select columns starting with "q" letter:

```
data[,grep("^[q]", colnames(data))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this...

```
data[,seq(1,ncol(data),2)][(data[,seq(2,ncol(data),2)]==1)|
                           (data[,seq(2,ncol(data),2)]==3)] <- NA

data
      A    qA     B    qB
1    NA     1     2     2
2     5     2     5     2
3     6     2    NA     1
4    NA     3    NA     3
5    NA     1    NA     1
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to separate in two tables and use vectorisation in base R

```r
data <-  data.frame(A = c(1,5,6,8,7), qA = c(1,2,2,3,1), B = c(2,5,6,8,4), qB = c(2,2,1,3,1))
data
#>   A qA B qB
#> 1 1  1 2  2
#> 2 5  2 5  2
#> 3 6  2 6  1
#> 4 8  3 8  3
#> 5 7  1 4  1

quality <- data[,grep("^[q]", colnames(data))]
data2 <- data[,setdiff(colnames(data), names(quality))]

data2[quality == 1 | quality == 3] <- NA
data2
#>    A  B
#> 1 NA  2
#> 2  5  5
#> 3  6 NA
#> 4 NA NA
#> 5 NA NA
```